# FragmentResultListeners are not restored when fragment is recreated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a fragment with the following menu item action

```
R.id.action_gotopage -> {
    GoToPageDialog()
        .show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, GoToPageDialog.TAG).also {
        setFragmentResultListener(GoToPageDialog.TAG) { _, bundle ->
            bundle.run {
                if (containsKey(PAGE_ID))
                    binding.pdfView.jumpTo(getInt(PAGE_ID))
                clearFragmentResultListener(GoToPageDialog.TAG)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`GoToPageDialog` is a `DialogFragment`. It works alright in normal contiditions, but when the fragments are recreated e.g. after Android killed the activity, the listener is no longer called.

Is that a bug or an expected behavior? What is the right way to handle it then?

Comment: No listener is going to survive a process death and recreation; that part is expected. Is there a reason you're not just always listening for results (i.e., adding the listener in a lifecycle method that is always called)?

Comment: There is no reason and that's excactly the way I made it work. Just wanted make sure it was not a but.